# Labels and textviews showing up as misaligned in simulator when using autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've recently been implementing a new project on Swift, targeting iOS 8+. The UI mixes storyboards and XIBs, using autolayout for everything.

I recently took a look at the application using the "color misaligned images" debug feature in the iOS simulator. All my images are fine but for some reason almost every label and textview I have is showing up as magenta, meaning they are supposedly misaligned. All of these views are aligned using autolayout, which is supposed to be very good at avoiding misalignment. Any thoughts on what is going on here?

**EDIT:**

Nevermind, turns out it was just another Stupid User Error. I forgot I had a scaling function for forcing downscaling on some fonts based on screensize. This was returning fractions which was causing the misalignment.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this will help?

http://blog.xebia.com/2013/07/19/ios-pixel-misalignment-why-its-bad-how-to-fix-it/

"How To Fix Pixel Misalignment?

Once you have found your culprit. It’s a good idea to start looking through your code to determine how the actual frame of the misaligned screen item is calculated. Some debugging will help you here. I’d look in any layoutSubviews or loadView calls for any divisions being performed on view frames. Also using Font metrics in your calculations is a common cause for misaligned images.

Most likely you will have found your culprit pretty soon. How to fix this? There are two ways to go about this. Either use a floorf or ceilf on the exact value causing the misalignment. Or pass the CGRect for the views frame through a CGRectIntegral call.

When it concerns an image on a retina device, make sure the retina version of that image is actually exactly twice the dimensions of the non retina image. Faulty dimensions on retina image resources is a common cause as well for pixel misalignment. So get check those image resources if they show up magenta."

Comment: The question was specific to autolayout. This is specific to non autolayout.